# Hive table data load gives NULL values

Tags: hive, hiveql, create-table, hiveddl

`Select * from movierating` gives NULL values as a Result.

I have tried below create table queries:

```
CREATE TABLE movierating(id INT, movieid INT, rating INT, time string);
CREATE TABLE movierating(id INT, movieid INT, rating INT, time string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' stored as textfile;
```

Tried below load queries:

```
load data local inpath '/tmp/Movie-rating.txt' into table movierating;
load data local inpath '/tmp/Movie-rating.txt' OVERWRITE into table movierating;
```

data into 'Movie-rating.txt' file:(delimeter is tab)

```
1     123      3   881250949   
2     125      4   881250123
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tab delimited data use `'\t'` as field delimiter:

```
CREATE TABLE movierating(id int,movieid int,rating int,time string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY  '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```